# stop firefox from going into offline mode

Tags: firefox

I am setting up a kiosk with firefox (portable 3.5, i'm going to grab 7 both installer and portable version).

On startup it runs bat file which starts my server, autohotkey and firefox (which has a kiosk extention). The problem is firefox is starting in offline mode which means it doesnt connect to my server. I googled and people suggest its because the network doesnt have an internet connection. The server is on the computer i dont need an internet connection! How do i get firefox to not startup in offline mode so it actually attempts to connect to my webpage/server?

Answer (score 0):

What's the startup page in your FF installation? If it's the default (a mixture of Google/FF), that might be the reason it's pinging the 'net. Change the default to be `about:blank`, or better yet, a page on your internal server.

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, as root, edit the file /etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf, and change all instances of:
>
> ```
> <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>
> to:
> <deny send_interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"/>
> ```
>
> Then save changes and reboot making sure that Work Offline was not checked when you last exited Firefox 3.

http://forums.techguy.org/linux-unix/719137-how-open-firefox-3-without.html